# Using regex for filterpatterns in AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to use the following regex in my cloudformation template but it looks like the regex is not working at all.
Here's what I am using:
`Item-Param[a-zA-Z]*-Issue`

So that it matches events from the Cloudwatch logs such as `Item-ParamXYZ-Issue` or `Item-ParamAppleIssue`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what exactly isn't working? It looks like it should match your first example, but the second example only has one `-` so your regex doesn't match that.

Comment: No the pattern is working fine. The cloudformation template isn't getting built because it is illegal to place a regex directly. So how am I supposed to match any string in the given pattern?

Comment: Well it doesn't look like regex is supported at all in EventBridge filters: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html so it's going to be impossible to do this. I think the best you can do is match on the prefix "Item-Param"

Comment: Are you looking to use CloudWatch Logs Insights? Because regex is supported there